# Oracle SQL Groupby and SUM

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum

I have the following query that groups every tender id and description and shows its total Sum:

```
3020    American Express             20
1000    Cash - primary currency      9903.25
3120    House Card                   2605.56
4070    Purchase Order               668.25
3000    Visa                         26005.19

SELECT B.TENDER_TYPE_ID, A.TENDER_TYPE_DESC, SUM (B.TENDER_AMT)
FROM POS_TENDER_TYPE_HEAD A, SA_TRAN_TENDER B, SA_TRAN_HEAD C
WHERE A.TENDER_TYPE_ID = B.TENDER_TYPE_ID AND B.TRAN_SEQ_NO = C.TRAN_SEQ_NO
GROUP BY B.TENDER_TYPE_ID, A.TENDER_TYPE_DESC
```

In the table **C (SA_TRAN_HEAD),** there is a field of **TRAN_DATETIME.**
I want the query to return the results falling between an interval of dates but do not want the date to appear in the query columns.

What could I do to achieve this ?

Comment: Just add that condition to the where clause? Is there a reason you think it's more complicated than that - have you tried and got an error, perhaps?

Comment: Hi Alex, 
Just misplaced the code lines and got some error. Then thought weirdly about complicated joins.

Thou it was very simple one. 

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the desired date range to the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT B.TENDER_TYPE_ID,
       A.TENDER_TYPE_DESC,
      SUM (B.TENDER_AMT)
FROM POS_TENDER_TYPE_HEAD A,
     SA_TRAN_TENDER B,
     SA_TRAN_HEAD C
WHERE A.TENDER_TYPE_ID = B.TENDER_TYPE_ID AND
      B.TRAN_SEQ_NO = C.TRAN_SEQ_NO AND
      C.TRAN_DATETIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JAN-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                          AND TO_DATE('31-MAR-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
GROUP BY B.TENDER_TYPE_ID,
         A.TENDER_TYPE_DESC
```

I also suggest you get used to using ANSI join syntax, as it makes the joins much clearer and is more transportable (particularly for outer joins). The following should be equivalent:

```
SELECT B.TENDER_TYPE_ID,
       A.TENDER_TYPE_DESC,
      SUM (B.TENDER_AMT)
FROM POS_TENDER_TYPE_HEAD A
INNER JOIN SA_TRAN_TENDER B
  ON B.TENDER_TYPE_ID = A.TENDER_TYPE_ID
INNER JOIN SA_TRAN_HEAD C
  ON C.TRAN_SEQ_NO = B.TRAN_SEQ_NO
WHERE C.TRAN_DATETIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JAN-2015 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                          AND TO_DATE('31-MAR-2015 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
GROUP BY B.TENDER_TYPE_ID,
         A.TENDER_TYPE_DESC
```

This makes it clear what the join criteria are, as opposed to the filter criteria.